# Dot Notation in SQL FROM clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to understand some example SQL code (without extra context, apart from the fact that it's Postgres).  I can't for the life of me work out what the dot notation in the following line means:

```
SELECT user_id INTO id FROM customer.user WHERE user_id=1;
```

What could 'customer.user' refer to exactly? What does this dot notation mean?

Comment: Schema customer, table user. (Not a very good table name...)

Comment: Damn - so simple - thanks!

Comment: are you really sure this is not described in the documentation? I think you should write to the postgres customer support and address this issue, if necessary.

Comment: I couldn't find it in the documentation, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, customer refers to database name and user refers to table name.Usually we follow FUlly qualified name for tables as database_name.table_name

Comment: I haven't accepted an answer as I don't know which is correct - database or schema?

Comment: we use both schema.tablename and dbname.table name.For details look on database vs schema description

Answer (score 0):

Customer is the database name and user is the table name.